# Including Bootstrap in more than one Rails engine overwrites custom definitions

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am working on extracting behavior from a Rails app, and packaging it as a rails engine, to be included as a gem in the original app. My team has already successfully done this with another piece of functionality.

For the purpose of this discussion we can call the existing rails engine `Foo` and the one I'm creating `Bar`.

`Foo` has its own set of scss stylesheets, some of which depend on variables imported from Bootstrap. `Bar` is going to as well.

The main app's application.scss looks like this:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'foo/application'; // main stylesheet for Foo
@import 'bar/application'; // main stylesheet for Bar
```

foo/application looks like this:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
.cc-tab__icon {
  @extend .lead;
  font-size: 12px;
} // class which extends the Bootstrap .lead class
```

bar/application:

```
@import 'bootstrap'; // needs bootstrap too
```

Now, with bootstrap re-imported, my .cc-tab__icon elements have `font-size 21px`, which comes from a @media declaration on Bootstrap's .lead class. If I leave `@import 'bar/application'` out of my main application.scss file my .cc-tab__icon elements have the correct 12px font size.

I think the issue must be something I don't understand about @media declarations. Why would re-importing the same library affect a class that's already been declared and which just extends a class of said library?

Comment: Can you qualify the CSS change with something like `.some-container .cc-tab__icon { ... }`?

Comment: @muistooshort I was thinking the same thing after I wrote this question. Now I realize I was asking the wrong question! .cc-tab__icon is a class defined in Foo which extends a class from Bootstrap, and it loses its font-size property when Bootstrap is re-imported.